# Calculate percentage of a data series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, calculation

I have a series of data and I would like to calculate the growth percentage value compared to the first date

```
Date:   1    2    3    4    5    6 .....
Price:  5    4    8   10   11   12
```

Starting from date 2, I would like to do ((4-5)/5)*100 which is -20. Date 3 is ((8-5)/5)*100 which is 100%. So it will become like this

```
Date:   1    2    3    4    5    6 .....
Price:  0  -20   60  100  120  140
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure, it is a series, not a datafame?

Comment: is your title wrong? i can not see anything about saving documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    "Price": [5, 4, 8, 10, 11, 12]})


date1 = df.loc[0, "Price"]  # price of first date
df["Price"] = df["Price"].apply(lambda x: ((x-date1)/date1)*100)
print(df)
#   Date  Price
#0     1    0.0
#1     2  -20.0
#2     3   60.0
#3     4  100.0
#4     5  120.0
#5     6  140.0
```

### Edit

This is to match exactly the OP's CSV file posted in the comments below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("fb_removed.csv", skiprows=1, header=None).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.T.loc[1:]
df.columns = ["Date", "Price"]

date1 = float(df.iloc[0]["Price"])  # price of first date
df["Price"] = df["Price"].apply(lambda x: ((float(x)-date1)/date1)*100)
print(df.head())
#        Date     Price
#1  2019/6/12  0.000000
#2  2019/6/13  1.388259
#3  2019/6/14  3.593469
#4  2019/6/17  7.981034
#5  2019/6/18  7.672537
```

Comment: Thanks guys. How about if I have many data(let say n date), not only Date 1 to Date 6?

Comment: This code will work if you have n date. I've created the same example like the one in your question to explain how it should work

Comment: I tried it a few time, if I type in df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2019/6/12", "2019/6/13", "2019/6/14"],
                    "Price": [175.04, 177.47, 177.98]})
It only calculates for the first 3 days.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: First of all, thanks for keep helping me.
Based on your answer, the first step is to put Date 1 to 6 and its Price to DataFram. But if there are 100 dates in my spreadsheet, how can I put all 100 dates and its Price into the DataFrame?
Thanks

Comment: First of all, it's OK we all are here for help :). Second of all, you can generate a dataframe from the spreadsheet easily using `pd.read_csv()` or `pd.read_excel`. Could you post the spreadsheet to your question and I will try to exactly adapt my solution to it

Comment: Here is the download link of the spreadsheet file.
https://mega.nz/file/iKJj1SBQ#fj7GLBtHQ0J1ji8Qdyfgsyub--VKuDJJJSnG9eoULQA

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Anwarvic.

I am trying to understand the code you wrote to me. May I know what is the purpose of the first line? (I am very new to Python and I want to learn something instead of copy&paste)
The 2nd line is to transpose the data, then the 3rd line is to label Date and Price columns.

Comment: OK, the first line is to read the data from `csv` file. But, the CSV file wasn't structured properly, so I needed to skip the first row and to reset any associated indeices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'price':[5,4,8,10,11,12]})

data['price'] = data['price'].transform(lambda x:((x-data['price'].iloc[0])/data['price'].iloc[0])*100).astype(int)

print(data)
```

Output:-

```
  date  price
0   1   0
1   2   -20
2   3   60
3   4   100
4   5   120
5   6   140
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a diction like so:

```
d = {1: 5,
     2: 4,
     3: 8,
     4: 10,
     5: 11,
     6: 12}

d2 = {k:((d[k]-5)/5)*100 for k in d.keys()}

print(d2)
```

Output:

```
{1: 0.0, 2: -20.0, 3: 60.0, 4: 100.0, 5: 120.0, 6: 140.0}
```

---

If you don't want decimal points:

```
d = {1: 5,
     2: 4,
     3: 8,
     4: 10,
     5: 11,
     6: 12}

d2 = {k:int(((d[k]-5)/5)*100) for k in d.keys()}

print(d2)
```

Output:

```
{1: 0, 2: -20, 3: 60, 4: 100, 5: 120, 6: 140}
```